# set range using string variable for column letter

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'd like to know how to write this range changing "G" to a string variable `strColumn`.

This is the code I want to change:

```
   Dim lastRowElemento As Integer
   lastRowElemento = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
   Set rngElemento = ws.Range("G2:G" & lastRowElemento)
```

Comment: `ws.Range(strColumn & "2:"  & strColumn & lastRowElemento)`

Comment: I haven't seen or used this as a requirement so far. Could you share the code where you mean to apply it i.e. there should be another (better way)? Also, why aren't you using the worksheet reference in the second line, i.e. `lastRowElemento = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row`?

Comment: Possibly also `lastRowElemento = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, strColumn).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Another way: `ws.Range(ws.cells(2, strColumn ),ws.cells(lastRowElemento,strColumn)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying OP's method, try this:

```
Sub TEST()
Dim ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range, sCol As String
    sCol = "G"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")    'change as required
    With ws.Columns(sCol)
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: I got a problem when I used this code. If I add ```Rng.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(2).Range("A2")``` after ```End With```, then it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: @vbabeginner I tested the code to copy the `Rng` to `Worksheet(2)` of the `Active.Workbook` using the line `Rng.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(2).Range("A2")` and it performed the copy successfully. Suggest to add a new question explaining your problem with enough details so it can be reproduced. Avoid vague statements such as *"It doesn't work"*, be specific. If you want you could add a comment with my ID to the question, so I will know your question is posted.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I'll do it

Answer (score 2):

### Reference a 'Non-Empty' Column Range

- There are actually two requirements:

  - `ColumnString = G` (I prefer *string* since e.g. `XFD` are letter**s**)
  - `FirstRow = 2`

  If you put them together, you get `G2` (think one, instead of two variables).
- Since using the `Find` method is more reliable than using the `End` property in finding the bottom-most (last) non-empty cell in a column, I used it to write the `RefColumn` function which in your case can be utilized in the following way:

  ```
  Set rngElemento = RefColumn(ws.Range("G2"))
  ```
- I'll leave it up to you if you're going to test if there is data (usually you know there is), but I prefer to keep at least a 'simplified' test in the code:

  ```
  If rngElemento is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
  ' Continue...
  ```

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RefColumnTEST()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = RefColumn(ws.Range("G2"))
    If rg Is Nothing Then ' the range 'G2:G1048576' is empty
        MsgBox "No data.", vbCritical
    Else
        MsgBox rg.Address(0, 0), vbInformation
    End If
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function
```

**Meeting Your Requirements**

- Similarly to my preferred way, you could use the `RefData` function:

```vb
Function RefData( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal ColumnIndex As Variant) _
As Range
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With ws.Columns(ColumnIndex).Resize(ws.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        Set RefData = _
            .Resize(.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious).Row - 1)
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

which you can utilize in the following way:

```
Set rngElemento = RefData(ws, "G")
Set rngElemento = RefData(ws, 7)
' or:
Const strColumn As String = "G"
Set rngElemento = RefData(ws, strColumn)
```

Comment: Just one enhancement: You could have a function `getLastRowRow(ws as worksheet)` for returning `ws.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious).Row`. This is one of the code snippets I always add to my projects - and by that nearly "forgot" the syntax for that find-part.

Comment: You mean `ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row`.

Comment: yes - copy/paste error :-)